# Which are the useful metrics to monitor in a Oracle database

Tags: database, oracle, performance, monitoring, exadata

I am looking to monitor an Oracle database.
Do you have an idea about the metrics useful that I have to monitor?
Thank you in advance for your help.

Answer (score 1):

As an administration question, this is probably not the right site for this question. However, Oracle provides excellent documentation. Which metrics you monitor depends on your objective: Just keeping the database running (e.g., memory, CPU, storage limits being reached), making it run fast (e.g., optimizing pl/sql code, looking for the longest queries in v$sql, missing indexes/full table scans), etc.

Check out: https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/TGDBA/title.htm

Comment: Hello Darkerlvy, I think that my question are fairly legitimate, i  looking to get the opinion of the DBAs. 
the documentation of oracle is vague ! thank you for your understanding

Comment: also this information is usually useful for developers for the preforemnce of our sql scripts :-)

Answer (score 0):

I think:

- CPU occupation
- Memory occupation
- Number of open sessions